# ros tutorial turtlesim running but no display in docker

Tags: ros, ros-noetic, docker, rosnode, turtlesim

I have just started learning ros from the tutorial given in their website. [Tutorial link](https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingNodes)
As i am using windows I wanted to learn in Ubuntu. So i am using docker version of the ros. but now while running

`rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node`

the following response i am getting is

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
[ INFO] [1705785514.877814756]: Starting turtlesim with node name /turtlesim
[ INFO] [1705785514.882275854]: Spawning turtle [turtle1] at x=[5.544445], y=[5.544445], theta=[0.000000]
```

But unfortunately i am unable to get the display. Initially as the node was not running i used `export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen`

is docker the issue her for not being able to see the GUI? How can i enable the display ?

Note before this i was facing [this error](https://forum.qt.io/topic/93247/qt-qpa-plugin-could-not-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-xcb-in-even-though-it-was-found)